# Serving Django MVC and Django Rest Framework from same Model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This may be an opinionated question but sorry I am too curious.

I learned to develop Django Model-View-Template websites ( multi page websites) and Django Rest Framework.

From the same Django Model can I create Rest API's and MVC templates together ?

I wanted to develop a Blog website that use session authentication and  based on MVC architecture. The same server should create API's because the Mobile app for the Blog may consume the API's and use Token Authentication (using Djoser).

If I use same User model for session and token authentication, Can mobile blog app users use their username and password to access website version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django REST Framework is just a collection of helpers to easily create HTTP endpoints that conform to REST behaviour, which mostly means conventions around `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`. You could code all this behaviour by hand using default Django, DRF just makes it a lot easier. The end result are simply specific routes which accept input and return output in specific formats to/from models.

Of course you can use that *in addition* to normal Django Views. It's just a different interface to your models and other business logic. Authentication can be the same, but typically you use some sort of token authentication for the API; that ultimately depends on how the API is supposed to be used exactly.